# Twitter json API foreign characters

Tags: php, json, twitter

I'm using the Twitter json API with PHP to show tweets on a website. I've now noticed that if the tweet contains a foreign character such as Ö then this shows up on the site ��.

In the json file the two question marks are \u00d6.

I'm using this script to get the json and decode it: http://pastebin.com/X3pjKrSi

Then I'm using jQuery ajax to put it on the site with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/functions/twitter/twitter.php',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "tweets=<?php echo $options['ct_tweets']; ?>&account=<?php echo $options['ct_twitter']; ?>",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#twitter-loader').remove();
                    $('#twitter-container').html(data);
                }
            });
       });
```

Does anyone know what I would have to do to display the foreign characters?

The same characters works fine in the rest of the site (built in Wordpress).

Thanks

Comment: Is the rest of the site in UTF-8?

Comment: Yes it is, through `<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />` which gets UTF-8 from the Wordpress setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inform the browser you will be outputting UTF-8 content. You can do this by adding:

```
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

At the beginning of your PHP code.

Comment: Do you mean I have to add that to the this PHP script http://pastebin.com/X3pjKrSi

Comment: That's what I mean. Try adding it at the beginning of the file, in the 2nd line, right after the opening <?php (you need to make sure it is sent before your first echo).

Comment: Wait, if you are calling this script with AJAX then you actually need to add this to the HTML of the calling page.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the actual page where the problem occurs?

Comment: It's not online I'm afraid. I'm developing locally on Server2Go as the site isn't finished.

Comment: Turns out it was my Server2Go install that caused the problems. I put the code on my VPS and it worked straight away so I think your answer was right all along just that I couldn't see it.