# json decode non-utf-8 chars

Tags: php, json

Hi I'm getting all of a user's statuses from twitter in json and there are some non-utf-8 characters in there (some spanish). Was wondering how I can keep the non-utf-8 chars in tact when calling json_decode?

thanks!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851113/twitter-json-api-foreign-characters/6851182#6851182

Comment: Spanish characters are part of UTF-8. In fact, you have to search pretty hard to find "non-UTF-8 characters". Do you mean they're just *not displayed correctly*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this at the very top of your document

```
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

however "non-utf-8" characters is very odd chain of characters